# How to navigate to MVC controller's action from View in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2019

When I am looking at an MVC.NET `view` (meaning, a `.cshtml` file) I often want to jump to the `action` of the `view` I'm on. I would love to hit a shortcut but there isn't one (that I've found).

During my own research, I found that in Visual Studio, I can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> or <kbd>CTR</kbd>L+<kbd>T</kbd> (they both appear to do the same thing) and that lets me navigate to a "thing" that matches my text search.

Cool, but I'd much rather have this direct. If my understanding is right, *usually* the `.cshtml` name matches the `action`, and the folder matches the `controller` and as such, it should be able to guess what my action is from this.

Is it possible to jump directly to the action for the `.cshtml` file with a simple shortcut?

Comment: *** Please note, I am aware my question is about navigation. It's not about the code, so I am concerned that it is off topic, but, I also feel that this is of most value here as it's about a programming IDE (Visual Studio). If it's off topic, please don't just downvote, please let me know as so I can remove/migrate if needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Ctrl+M, Ctrl+G` (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> as a combination (without releasing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> until after you press <kbd>G</kbd>)) it will navigate you back to the controller and you can switch between the view and controller using the same key shortcut. However its always navigate to a single controller, you can't find how many actions are using this view by using this shortcut.

Comment: Argh... I had seen that but didn't realise it was both at once... I kept hitting CTRL+M and seeing my functions collapse :( 
Thank you

Comment: Not at once click the first combination then the second.

Answer (score 0):

Just Press Ctrl + MG together and you will in your controller.